# SQL Server 2008R2 Merge

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

How to Merge stage and final tables using Merge command in SQL Server without final table having primary key?

Should I compare all the columns fields after ON in Merge Statement?

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` does not require an explicit primary key. You should be able to do that with *any* criteria that can uniquely identify a row. (That begs the question though - why does your table not have a primary key?)